# MongoDB unique index errors: how to know which field generated the error?

Tags: mongodb

***Update**: this question was asked in regards to MongoDB 1.8.x and the accepted solution pertains to 1.8. Note, however, that Mongo 2.x has made changes to the error messages so that you can tell which fields generate the errors on the update as well as the insert (see comments from Kyle and Remon below).*

**Is there a way to attempt a Mongo upsert and, if there is a unique index violation, know which field is causing the problem--all in one database operation?**

For example, say I have a `customers` collection with `_id` and `name` properties. Also, say a [unique index](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-UniqueIndexes) exists for `name` to ensure that a no two `customer` docs ever have the same `name`.

Currently, I do *two* database operations to perform an upsert:

1. Query `customers` to see if a document already exists with the name that I'm about to insert/update.
2. Do the upsert if no conflict exists.

I'd like to be able to do this in a single operation and, if there's an error, know which field is causing the problem.

This is sort of possible if the operation is to create a new document. Mongo returns the error **`E11000 duplicate key error index: {index name}`**. It's a bit of a hack, but I can use a regex to parse out the index name (which in my case, has the field name in it).

However, when *updating* a document the error message has no information about the index or field. It's simply "**`E11001 duplicate key on update`**".

Does anyone else have suggestions about smart ways to do upserts and know which fields are causing unique index problems, if necessary? Hoping to avoid [server-side stored JavaScript functions](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Storingfunctionsserverside)...

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you running? This appears to be fixed in 2.0.1.

Comment: It is. I just tested it and it gives the offending index during an upsert as well

Comment: I'm using 1.8.x, but it's great to know about this change in 2.x. Thanks @KyleBanker and @RemonvanVliet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For insert, parsing error message is your best bet. For update, unfortunately, there is no better way except trying to check against existing data in the collection. Feel free to raise an enhancement at https://jira.mongodb.org though.